# Web Api string parameter (fromQuery) always null when posted with value (FromBody)

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, postman

I am using web api 2 and .net core 2.0

I'm trying to post to an endpoint but the `propertyId` in the in the query is always null, but the `value` in the body is populated. If I change `propertyId` to an `int`, it gets populated.

After LOTS of reading I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing#get-books-by-genre), which has "confirmed" - for me - that what I've done should be working. It's not so I don't know what I'm missing. There are many threads on this issue but none have helped me. Could someone please advise what i'm missing?

I have tried a number of variations, including:

- passing the query as ?propertyId=teststring
- Removing [FromQuery]
- Removing Route
- Changing headers
- Combos of above

  ```
  public class RoomsController : ControllerBase
  {
      ...other stuff...

  [HttpPost, Route("{propertyId}")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromQuery]string propertyId, [FromBody]List<CreateRoomRequestDto> value)
  {
      List<Guid> result = await _mediator.Send(new NewRoomRequest() { PropertyId = propertyId, NewRoom = value });
      return Ok(result);
  }
  }
  ```

http://localhost:49942/api/Rooms/testString

**the postman script**

```
POST /api/Rooms/testString HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:49942
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Postman-Token: f15b569d-84a2-4bde-bdf0-b1cdf3fff975

[
    {
        "Tag":"30dd879c-ee2f-11db-8314-0800200c9a66",
        "Name":"testName",
        "Description": "tesDescription",
        "Length": 1.5,
        "Width": 1.8,
        "Dimension": 5,
        "DimensionText": "some DimensionText test",
        "PhotoUrls": ["klklkl", "oioioioii"]
    },
    {
        "Tag":"30dd879c-ee2f-11db-8314-0800200c9a66",
        "Name":"testName2",
        "Description": "tesDescription2",
        "Length": 1.2,
        "Width": 1.9,
        "Dimension": 5,
        "DimensionText": "some DimensionText test2",
        "PhotoUrls": ["klklklwewe", "oioioioiinmnmnm"]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is name the `[FromQuery]` attribute like this

`[FromQuery(Name = "propertyId")]`

I've been looking through the .NET Core routing code recently and it seems like `[FromQuery]` just needs some help, from time to time, to know which pieces of the query string to map from.

EDIT: Oh, and also take your route attribute off so that it's clear where the parameter is coming from. As well as make your request use an actual query string like

`?propertyId=testString` instead of making it the ID on the route.